# How can a Psionic Manifester get full BAB reliably?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

I’m currently trying to make a Talshatora Monk/Erudite multiclass work, partially as a challenge and partially because I want to play a psionic Gish. The issue is that, under the constraints i’m operating under, getting a BaB high enough to function in melee will be difficult. So, I’ve looked into somehow persisting or otherwise gaining a at will or permanent Divine Power like effect.

My build goals are 9th level psionic powers with Divine Power, or barring that Transformation. These are the constraints and rules assumptions i’m working under for this game.

- Prestige classes that advance manifesting are ruled psionic classes so having more levels in one of them than my Erudite level will cause issues, this is why Slayer is unfortunately off the table.
- Spell to Power Erudite is in use however spells not normally available to arcane classes, such as Divine Power being gained by the Arcane Disiple feat, are not easily obtainable. They can be gained theoretically but aren't reliable. So while Persist Power Divine Power is an option in theory it’s not something I can bank on.
- Custom Item creation Rules, specifically Custom Wondrous Items of Divine Power or infinite use resetting traps of Divine Power, are off the table.
- Permanent Runes of Divine Power are allowed, but the expense obviously makes it a less than ideal option.
- All first party books, as well as dragon and dungeon magazine, are allowed. The game is also fairly high optimization with one other player using Astral Seed to transform into a dragon, this however doesn’t work on spells that don’t change your body. So I can’t use that strategy to make divine power permanent. (Unless I can find a convincing argument for why it would)
- There is effectively no cap on how much of our WBL can be spent on a single item.

My current plans if I can’t find a better solution is to either get Divine Power as a psionic power somehow and persist it or get the extend and persist spell feats and apply persist spell to a wand of Divine Power using a schema of metamagic item.

Comment: What about Magic Jar shenanigans? You need a body with a soul, so dragons work well, as they have +1 BAB per HD. You jump into a dragon, then cast Magic Jar from the Dragon's body and jump into another body. Then break the first jar (which should kill you, but since you are neither in the dragon's body nor the gem, the spell does not say what happens). So, you can jump back to the dragon's body which is yours now, permanently. Is broken stuff like that possible? (A DM could and should rule that you just die by doing this, but gotta ask).

Comment: Actually a true mind switch with a dragon would be a viable option though I believe I keep my own BaB. Granted with a strength that high and a absurd number of natural weapons I would still be effective. It’s about as powerful as what another player is doing with astral seed exploit making what is effectively a instantaneous duration Polymorph so I could do that. Though if possible I’d like to stick with a humanoid form for character reasons, but it’s not a bad idea if I need something for a boost.

Comment: Monk 1/Erudite 7/Slayer 6/Sanctified Mind 6 has ML 17 (high enough for 9th lvl powers),a BAB of +16, and is possible if your DM allows fractions to add (Monk 1 grants 0.75 BAB while slayer 7 grants 3.5 BAB for a total of 4.25, qualifying you for Slayer). This ensures that no prestige class level goes over your Erudite level. With Practiced Manifester, you can get your ML up to 20.

Comment: Or there is the Psychokinetic Champion from Complete Mage (page 52). It is not fleshed out at all, only briefly mentioned as an available 'adaptation' to Abjurant champion.

Comment: If you’re not married to the Erudite you could instead do the Ardent class with the customizable mantle ACF. Better BAB and the multiclassing won’t slow down you getting access to higher level powers

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in your post, *metamagic item* with a wand of *divine power* works, but you could also, more cheaply, use a minor schema of *concurrent infusions* to imitate *spell-storing item* to make a 1-charge wand of *divine power,* doing so more cheaply (11,800gp for the schema of *concurrent infusions* compared to a 21,000gp wand of *divine power*) and without worrying about consumable charges.